# Mysql query grouping results in php / moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have a mysql query:

```
SELECT
mdl_user_info_data.data,
mdl_user.firstname, 
mdl_user.lastname, 
mdl_grade_grades.itemid, 
mdl_grade_items.itemname,
mdl_course.cpd,
mdl_grade_grades.timecreated AS DATE
FROM mdl_user
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades ON mdl_user.id = mdl_grade_grades.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.courseid
INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
WHERE mdl_grade_grades.timecreated >= '1370091991'
AND mdl_grade_grades.timecreated <= '1370524243'
AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1
```

The query executes correctly and in phpmyadmin, it shows correctly. there are 4 records.
some of these records have the same usernames eg:

```
09118514    Elazabi Gillyman    108 Career Management1  1370508988
09118514    Elzaabi Gillyman    108 Career Management2  1370508988
03228812    Magria  Martinia    171 NULL    4           1370294859
03228812    Magria  Martinia    171 Making Budgeting    1370294859
```

But when I try and use this in php, there are only 2 records:

```
09118514    Elazabi Gillyman    108 Career Management2  1370508988
03228812    Magria  Martinia    171 Making Budgeting    1370294859
```

I assume that somehow the records with the same id's are being grouped, but I need to see all the results. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the exact query:

```
$sql = "SELECT
        mdl_user_info_data.data,
        mdl_user.firstname, 
        mdl_user.lastname, 
        mdl_grade_grades.itemid, 
        mdl_grade_items.itemname,
        mdl_course.cpd,
        mdl_grade_grades.timecreated AS DATE
        FROM mdl_user
        INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades ON mdl_user.id = mdl_grade_grades.userid
        INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items ON mdl_grade_grades.itemid = mdl_grade_items.courseid
        INNER JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_course.id
        INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data ON mdl_user.id = mdl_user_info_data.userid
        WHERE mdl_grade_grades.timecreated >= '1370091991'
        AND mdl_grade_grades.timecreated <= '1370524243'
        AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid = 1";

$users = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
var_dump($users);
```

the var_dump fives this result (please note, I had edited out some fields for readability):

```
array(5) { 
  [20038617]=> object(stdClass)#387 (7) { ["data"]=> string(8) "20038617" ["firstname"]=> string(9) "Bhekumuzi" ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Shongwe" ["itemid"]=> string(2) "72" ["itemname"]=> string(21) "Delegating Assessment" ["cpd"]=> string(4) "2.00" ["date"]=> string(10) "1370518594" } 

["03429262"]=> object(stdClass)#388 (7) { ["data"]=> string(8) "03429262" ["firstname"]=> string(7) "Shirlee" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "Levey" ["itemid"]=> string(3) "100" ["itemname"]=> string(27) "The IFRS Agenda part 2 quiz" ["cpd"]=> string(4) "0.25" ["date"]=> string(10) "1370431311" } 

[10001873]=> object(stdClass)#386 (7) { ["data"]=> string(8) "10001873" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "Bertha" ["lastname"]=> string(11) "Muchineripi" ["itemid"]=> string(3) "103" ["itemname"]=> string(45) "State of the nation analysis 2012 part 3 quiz" ["cpd"]=> string(4) "0.25" ["date"]=> string(10) "1370255012" } 

["09118514"]=> object(stdClass)#385 (7) { ["data"]=> string(8) "09118514" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "Elzabi" ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Gillman" ["itemid"]=> string(3) "108" ["itemname"]=> string(17) "Career Management" ["cpd"]=> string(4) "2.00" ["date"]=> string(10) "1370508988" } 

["03228812"]=> object(stdClass)#383 (7) { ["data"]=> string(8) "03228812" ["firstname"]=> string(5) "Maria" ["lastname"]=> string(6) "Martin" ["itemid"]=> string(3) "172" ["itemname"]=> string(90) "Managerial Megatrends and Financial Control Quiz - pass the quiz for automatic CPD logging" ["cpd"]=> string(1) "4" ["date"]=> string(10) "1370297204" } }
```

Comment: can you provide `var_dump($query)` so we can compare those two?

Comment: Have you made sure that the query PHP is using is the exact same query that you entered into PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: @Mladen the var_dump give us the exact data as the second example with the other records removed.

Comment: I wasn't asking for result set, but for the sql query string :)

Comment: @Wayne Whitty, yes, the sql is exactly the same which is what has me flumoxed. I am copying the query straight from phpmyadmin into netbeans.

Comment: @user1882752 can you please add your PHP code here ..with a sql fiddle

Comment: @WayneWhitty (sorry, heres the other bits)

Comment: @user1882752 your new result is neither 4 nor 2 ..are you sure with the query??

Comment: @swapnesh I edited the results for readability, there are actually 29 records, which php reduces to 5. I tried to display the actual problem in the 2 examples.

Comment: Looks like you're using the moodle api. Is that correct? When you assert "when I try and use this in php, there are only 2 (or 5 or whatever) records," please tell us *precisely* how you know this. How do you count those records?

Comment: @OllieJones, yes it is Moodle.  I have included the php code where I populate the $users array.  I then do a foreach($users as $user) loop and I only get the 5 records. If I do a count($users) the total is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moodle documentation at http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_an_hashed_array_of_records says that the API call you're using (`get_records_sql`) retrieves a hashed array of records indexed by the first column of your query.  The documentation says

> The array is indexed by the first column of the fields returned by the
>   query. Thus to assure consistent data, it appears to be best practice
>   to ensure that your query include an "id column" as the first field.

"Appears to be best practice?"  Heh heh. That's a model of understatement.

So, you're getting one item in your hashed array for each distinct value of `mdl_user_info_data.data` in the result of your query. The moodle `get_records_sql` method is functioning as it was designed.

Moodle also offers a recordset API. This is what you want. http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Using_Recordsets

Try something like this.

```
$recordset = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql);
foreach ($recordset as $user) {
    // Do whatever you want with this user's record
}
$recordset ->close(); // Don't forget to close the recordset!
```